# Who's messing with my router?

Tags: wifi, iptables

Recently, I've been feeling that somebody is doing bad things to my Access point.
My wifi access point is "protected" with a hidden ssid, and a WPA2 password. Nobody granted access apart from me, however, around 10PM almost every day, my ping goes from 50-60, to 3k.

Today I did the smart thing, and disabled the wifi. As soon as I disabled it (I'm using cable for my computer) ping got back to normal.

My router does have a unix embedded, which I can access via SSH.

I've access to the shell, so I've checked if I do have iptables on it.

`iptables -V` reports:

> iptables v1.4.6

So two questions came over my mind:

- Is there a way I can detect attacks on my WiFi?
- If I set up a WireShark on my computer, can I forward all trafic generated from & to the router, to that computer with WireShark so I can find out which Mac address is doing nasty things? If so, how?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How about just running `tcpdump` and using it to observe the traffic appearing ?

Comment: sh: tcpdump: not found

Comment: @What version of *nix is your router running?  What's the output to `lsb_release --short --codename&&uname --kernel-release`?  At least we'll be able to tell you how to install tcpdump (if at all possible)...

Comment: /proc/versionfile reports the following: Linux version 2.6.30.9 (zhangzhihua@soft) (gcc version 4.4.6 (Realtek RSDK-1.5.6p2) ) #245 Mon Nov 24 18:32:12 CST 2014. uname is not available so I can't use it

Comment: Can you be sure that it is not simply the 24h reconnect many ISPs force upon you? Maybe check your routers (public) IP before and after - if you have a dynamic IP they should be different.

Comment: @Fiximan Makes no sense that just after disabling wifi, it goes back to normal then

Answer (score 4):

towards the first item (quickly & easily):

- from the router, you should be able to use `netstat -natp` to show you a list of all active tcp connections.
- from your pc, try using `nmap -v -sn 192.168.1.0/24` (substitute with your local net) to run a basic ping scan your local net. this should show you everyone connected (even via wifi).

towards the second item:

you probably could, but honestly.. that may be some pretty complex routing. you'd be better served to run something like `airmon-ng` (part of the `aircrack-ng` suite) on your pc - it'll use your pc's wifi adapter (in monitor mode) to capture packets.

other thoughts/possibilities:

- if you're an comcast user, google "xfinitywifi"; their hardware is set up to activate a second hotspot on many user's wifi routers.
- check to see if there are any other strong wifi signals popping up on the same channel as your router.
- run some diagnostics on your router? i had a wifi router die after years of faithful service, but it did so in a horrifying fashion: intermittent horrible ping times, dns lookup failures, random dhcp address assignments...